# using str_replace_all to replace / with \

Tags: r, string, str-replace, stringr

I'm working through R for Data Science and one of the exercises asks me to replace all forward slashes with backslashes. I can't get this to work.

```
> x <- c("//w+", "//b[aeiou]//b")
> str_replace_all(x, "/", "\\")
[1] "w+"        "b[aeiou]b"
```

The online solution doesn't work either, as it replaces one forward slash with two backslashes.

```
> x <- c("//w+", "//b[aeiou]//b")
> str_replace_all(x, "/", "\\\\")
[1] "\\\\w+"            "\\\\b[aeiou]\\\\b"
```

Edit: I'm adding this to clarify my question. I literally want the string "//" to be "\\". I can't get that to happen. Here's an example in action showing how it's not working.

This works because I have used \ correctly in the string:

```
> x <- "\\w+'\\w+"
> sentence <- "Open the crate but don't break the glass."
> str_extract(sentence, x)
[1] "don't"
```

This doesn't work. I mistakenly used / instead of \ and try to use str_replace_all to fix this:

```
> y <- "//w+'//w+"
> z <- str_replace_all(y, "/", "\\\\")
> str_extract(sentence, z)
[1] NA
```

That's because z is not "\\w+'\\w+" like I want it to be, but rather:

```
> z
[1] "\\\\w+'\\\\w+"
```

Comment: Btw, you can also do this with base R - `gsub("/", "\\\\", x)`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution given online is actually working correctly! The extra backslashes that you're seeing are the [escape characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) necessary for other functions to correctly interpret the presence of `\` characters.

The following commands:

```
x <- c("//w+", "//b[aeiou]//b")
y <- str_replace_all(x, "/", "\\\\")
```

Produce new vector `y`. When printed to the R console, you'll see this:

```
[1] "\\\\w+"            "\\\\b[aeiou]\\\\b"
```

This looks wrong, but it isn't. Again, the extra backslashes are there to escape the literal backslashes. If you feed these strings to a function that *interprets* strings, you'll see that the string representation is actually correct, with each forward slash replaced with a backslash:

```
message(y)
\\w+\\b[aeiou]\\b

cat(y)
\\w+ \\b[aeiou]\\b
```

Answer (score 1):

`str_replace_all(x, "/", "\\\\")`and`str_replace_all(x, "/", "\\")`both are working in r for this problem